# Karate Test Framework: how can I sign XML using p12?

Tags: soap, karate

Karate Test Framework: Does this framework provide ability to sign soap xml request using p12 key ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, but you can easily plug-in a few lines of Java code to do this. Note that Karate just sends the whole XML as plain-text, it is up to you to create the right shape, including signatures or Base64 encoded chunks.

Please refer to the docs for Java interop: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java

You can look at the JWT example for some ideas: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/jwt/jwt.feature